# how to retrieve data from 3 tables by checking if one public column value is present in a result list

Tags: sql-server

I have 5 tables:

Users, countries ,Houses, Cars and Computers.

User table has the following columns:
- Id
- Name
- CountryId

Houses table has the following columns:
- Id
- UserId
- CountryLocationId

Cars table have has following columns:
- Id
- UserId
- CountryLocationId

Computers table has the following columns:
- Id
- UserId
- CountryLocationId

Countries table has the following columns:
- Id
- Name

I want to do something like this:

```
select distinct(Id) from Users where Id in(     

    select UserId from Houses where ContryLocationId in (select Id from Countries)

    select UserId from Cars where ContryLocationId in (select Id from Countries)

    select UserId from Computers where ContryLocationId in (select Id from Countries)
)
```

but i want to re-use the result from (select Id from Countries) instead of call it again.

Comment: Plug it into a variable, or load it into a temp table or table variable (if it's more than one value).

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably use a temp table.

```
SELECT INTO TEMP_COUNTRIES (select Id from Countries)
```

Then you can join to that for your remaining queries:

```
select UserId from Cars C
inner join temp_countries tc
  on c.ContryLocationId = tc.id
```

Answer (score 0):

I know using IN operator again and again will hurt the performance but you can use the better option of using EXISTS operator.

```
;WITH CTE 
AS
 (
    select UserId, ContryLocationId from Houses   
    UNION ALL
    select UserId, ContryLocationId from Cars 
    UNION ALL
    select UserId, ContryLocationId from Computers 
  )
select distinct(U.Id) 
from Users U
WHERE EXISTS (
              SELECT 1 
              FROM CTE C
              WHERE C.UserId = U.ID
              AND EXISTS (
                          SELECT 1 
                          FROM Countries
                          WHERE C.ContryLocationId = Countries.Id
                         )
              )
```

### OR

```
;WITH CTE 
AS
 (
    select UserId from Houses WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                                            FROM Countries
                                            WHERE Houses.ContryLocationId = ID)
    UNION ALL
    select UserId from Cars  WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                                            FROM Countries
                                            WHERE Houses.ContryLocationId = ID)
    UNION ALL
    select UserId from Computers  WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                                            FROM Countries
                                            WHERE Houses.ContryLocationId = ID)
  )
select distinct(U.Id) 
from Users U
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM CTE C
              WHERE C.UserId = U.ID
              )
```

Comment: I think the OP is just looking to avoid re-running the `(select Id from Countries)` bit.